# Recursive function in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

EDIT:

The code i provide includes a asynchron task in each interation, therefor i need the recursive function, my question is how to beautify the code and apply the proper use.

I want to:

- Remove the `processTask();` function call and let it call itself instead.
- Choose the best function declaration.

  ```
  connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) return throwSQLError(err, req, res, connection);

      var rowLength = rows.length;
      var taskIteration = 0;

      // Iterate over all tasks with a recursive function
      var processTask = function () {
          if (taskIteration < rowLength) {
              // I do asynch stuff and call those two lines below
              // in the callback of the asynch operation.
              taskIteration++;
              processTask();
          }
          else {
              // Send JSON to result
              res.json(inputArray);

              // Close MySQL connection
              connection.end();
          }
      };
      processTask();
  });
  ```

I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
function processTask(){ // Which function creator to use?
    if (taskIteration < rowLength) {
        // I do asynch stuff and call those two lines below
        // in the callback of the asynch operation.
        taskIteration++;
        processTask();
    }
    else {
        // Send JSON to result
        res.json(inputArray);

        // Close MySQL connection
        connection.end();
    }
}(); // instead of the explicit function call, call the function calls itself
```

Comment: Could you supply *all* of your code? Answers may likely be different given that you're excluding the closure which contains `connection`, `res`, `taskIteration` and `rowLength`.

Comment: Those closure variables are essentially dispensable, they are part of a node.js mySQL connection and a express.js path and two ints defining for the loop. I basically just want to iterate over my results recursively, but i feel like this solution is not the very best. But if you really think that'd help i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) return throwSQLError(err, req, res, connection);

    rows.forEach(function (row) {
        // do what you need to with each row;
    });

    /* or maybe even
    var result = rows.map(function (row) {
        // do what you need to with row and return it
    });
    and then do something with result
    */
    res.json(inputArray); // Not clear from the question where inputArray has come from 
    connection.end();
}
```

Comment: I think my initial question was articulated really bad, i edited in hope of improvement.